# How to import a custom class into mxml file in Flex? (Actionscript 3)

Tags: class, actionscript, import

i need to import my own class to the mxml file, but allways comes an error that classes cant be nested. I dont know how to use my classes (example: NetConn.as). Can you help me?

```
<!--language:actionscript3>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" firstView="views.eazyRadioHomeView">
    <fx:Style source="eazyRadio.css"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            include "NetConn.as";

            import myNetConn;
            var easy=new NetConnectionEx();
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Platzieren Sie nichtvisuelle Elemente (z. B. Dienste, Wertobjekte) hier -->

    </fx:Declarations>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
import com.yournamespace.NetConn;
```

instead of

```
include "NetConn.as"
```